# Python: changing global variable and global list elements inside a function

Tags: python, list, global-variables, python-3.3

**Problem**

I've come across another problem with my code. I am making a program that manipulates the value of a global variable as needed. I was looking on how to use `global` to change values of the global variable whenever needed inside a function. any help would be much appreciated. you can revise the whole code if you like. Again, thanks.

**Code**

```
verifier = 0
letters = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I"]

if verifier == 0:
    letters = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I"]
if verifier == 1:
    letters = newlist()

def newlist():
     numbers = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"]
     return animals

def main():
    global verifier
    # this should print ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I"]
    print(letters) 
    # global variable should be changed to 1
    verifier = 1 
    # this should print ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"] now
    print(letters) 
main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [global](http://www.diveintopython.net/html_processing/locals_and_globals.html) variable:

```
verifier = 0

def newlist():
    if verifier == 0:
        return ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I"]
    elif verifier == 1:
        return ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"]

print newlist()

def main():
    global verifier
    verifier = 1
main()

print newlist()
```

You had wrong code structure. You will not achieve anything by changing the variable.

It's variables declaration:

```
verifier = 0
letters = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I"]
```

First if and second if code won't will be checked only once, before calling main. Also - read about `elif`.

```
if verifier == 0:
    letters = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I"]
elif verifier == 1:
    letters = newlist()
```

"letters" in `main` fuinction always will `["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I"]`. See my example if you want to fix your code. `if` performed only one time. You will not be able to re-scan without having to restart your file.

In most cases `global` don't have to use - you simply pass the variable to the function arguments:

```
def newlist(verifier):
    if verifier == 0:
        return ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I"]
    elif verifier == 1:
        return ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"]

def main():
    print newlist(0)
    print newlist(1)
main()
```

Specifically on this task - there is not even need to use the functions:

```
letters = {
    0: ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I"],
    1: ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"]
}

print letters.get(0, None)
```

Comment: is there a way to have the `letters` global variable?